# chisel3: Want to use Vec, but need to use IndexedSeq

Tags: chisel

In generating a tapped shift register using "scanLeft", I needed to use a IndexedSeq of registers and explicit copying of the result of scanLeft to an output wire. Here are four examples (with testbench). Only the first one works.
I like the second one best, and wonder why it is not correct.

```
package tsr

import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._
import chisel3.iotesters._
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, FlatSpec}

object TappedShiftRegister {

  def apply[ T <: Data]( d : T, n : Int) : Vec[T] = {
    val rs = IndexedSeq.tabulate( n){ (i) => Reg( d.cloneType)}
    val rs0 = rs.scanLeft( d){ case (x, r) => r := x; r}
    val ys = Wire( Vec( n+1, d.cloneType))
    (ys zip rs0).foreach{ case (y,r) => y := r}
    ys
  }

  def apply1[ T <: Data]( d : T, n : Int) : Vec[T] = { // ChiselException
    val rs = Vec.tabulate( n){ (i) => Reg( d.cloneType)}
    Vec( rs.scanLeft( d){ case (x, r) => r := x; r})
  }

  def apply2[ T <: Data]( d : T, n : Int) : Vec[T] = { // ChiselException
    val rs = IndexedSeq.tabulate( n){ (i) => Reg( d.cloneType)}
    Vec( rs.scanLeft( d){ case (x, r) => r := x; r})
  }

  def apply3[ T <: Data]( d : T, n : Int) : Vec[T] = { // Wrong values
    val rs = Vec.tabulate( n){ (i) => Reg( d.cloneType)}
    val rs0 = rs.scanLeft( d){ case (x, r) => r := x; r}
    val ys = Wire( Vec( n+1, d.cloneType))
    (ys zip rs0).foreach{ case (y,r) => y := r}
    ys
  }

}

class TappedShiftRegisterIfc extends Module {
  val io = IO( new Bundle {
    val inp = Input( UInt(8.W))
    val out = Output( Vec( 5, UInt(8.W)))
  })
}

class GenericTSRTest( factory : () => TappedShiftRegisterIfc) extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  it should "meet all PeekPokeTester expectations" in {
    chisel3.iotesters.Driver( factory, "firrtl") { c => new PeekPokeTester(c) {
      val N = 4
      val off = 47
      for { i <- 0 until 100} {
        poke( c.io.inp, off+i)
        expect( c.io.out(0), off+i) // mealy output
        step(1)
        for { j <- 0 until N if i > j} {
          expect( c.io.out(j+1), off+i-j) // moore outputs
        }
      }
    }} should be (true)
  }
}

class TSRTest  extends GenericTSRTest( () => new TappedShiftRegisterIfc { io.out := TappedShiftRegister( io.inp, 4) })
class TSRTest1 extends GenericTSRTest( () => new TappedShiftRegisterIfc { io.out := TappedShiftRegister.apply1( io.inp, 4)})
class TSRTest2 extends GenericTSRTest( () => new TappedShiftRegisterIfc { io.out := TappedShiftRegister.apply2( io.inp, 4)})
class TSRTest3 extends GenericTSRTest( () => new TappedShiftRegisterIfc { io.out := TappedShiftRegister.apply3( io.inp, 4)})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First.  The following, closest to what you like, works. I added to your test suite.

```
def apply4[ T <: Data]( d : T, n : Int) : Vec[T] = { // No ChiselException!
  val rs = Seq.fill(n){ Reg(d.cloneType)}
  VecInit(rs.scanLeft(d){ case (x, r) => r := x; r})
}
class TSRTest4 extends GenericTSRTest( () => new TappedShiftRegisterIfc { io.out := TappedShiftRegister.apply4( io.inp, 4)})
```

Details:

- The **Vec.tabulate** has been deprecated, use **VecInit** instead.
- Using **VecInit** instead of the **Seq** resulted in an extra delay.  I'm still trying to figure that out, but the rule of thumb, should be don't create **Vec**s unless you really need them. And in this case you only need the one **Vec** so that you can assign it directly to the output IO.
- It's pretty easy to see the problem in the Firrtl file.

Comment: `val rs = Reg(Vec(n, d.cloneType))` also works.  The old "Use Reg of Vecs instead of Vec of Regs" rule

Comment: Thanks. Should we have a deprecation message (or compiler error) if we shouldn't use feature?

Comment: It would be nice, but Richard says this is hard. My goal is to improve documentation here for the moment.